# VB control styles change for unknown reason and cannot change back

Tags: vb.net, properties, styles, controls

For some reason while I program in **Microsoft Visual Basic 2010 Express** OR **VS Express for Desktop** my controls seem to change style for an unknown reason.

This screenshot is in the DESIGN part of my programming:

[image: Design UI]

And here is when I actually run the program:

[image]

I don't understand how it can change like that, I've tried changed properties on all the controls, but they just keep changing to whatever style that is...

I can update with more screenshots if need be.

Thanks

Comment: Doesnt it have to do with the Enable XP Styles (or `Application.EnableVisualStyles()`) ?  I know checkboxes change quite a bit depending on that

Comment: I meant comboboxes not checkboxes

Comment: @Plutonix YES! That fixed it! I'll answer my own question unless you do, then I'll accept yours

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer given via a comment:

Using `Application.EnableVisualStyles()` Fixes the whole thing.

Thanks to @Plutonix for the answer!